# Unable to calculate/update Theta value for d-q transformation (Park Transformation)

Tags: arduino, iteration, arduino-ide, st-link

I am trying to perform a d-q transformation on a signal after performing a clark transformation, but I am unable to calculate/update the theta value required for the transformation. I suspect there is a problem with the line "Theta[n+1]=Theta[n]+(2PI)(fo*Ts);" in my code. I am using an Arduino IDE and STM32f103 for the PLL and PI controller as part of a project on a three-phase voltage source inverter with current controlling technique.

**CODE:**

```
#include <math.h> 
double Ia[]={
  1,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.98,0.98,0.97,0.96,0.96
  ,0.951056516295154,0.940880768954226,0.929776485888251,0.917754625683981,0.904827052466020,0.891006524188368,0.876306680043864,0.860742027003944,0.844327925502015,0.827080574274562,0.809016994374948,0.790155012375690,0.770513242775789,0.750111069630460,0.728968627421412,0.707106781186548,0.684547105928689,0.661311865323652,0.637423989748690,0.612907053652977,0.587785252292473,0.562083377852131,0.535826794978997,0.509041415750371,0.481753674101715,0.453990499739547,0.425779291565073,0.397147890634781,0.368124552684678,0.338737920245291,0.309016994374947,0.278991106039229,0.248689887164855,0.218143241396542,0.187381314585725,0.156434465040231,0.125333233564304,0.0941083133185143,0.0627905195293133,0.0314107590781284,-1.60812264967664e-16,-0.0314107590781283,-0.0627905195293134,-0.0941083133185144,-0.125333233564304,-0.156434465040231,-0.187381314585725,-0.218143241396543,-0.248689887164855,-0.278991106039229,-0.309016994374947,-0.338737920245291,-0.368124552684678,-0.397147890634780,-0.425779291565073,-0.453990499739547,-0.481753674101715,-0.509041415750371,-0.535826794978997,-0.562083377852131,-0.587785252292473,-0.612907053652977,-0.637423989748690,-0.661311865323652,-0.684547105928689,-0.707106781186548,-0.728968627421411,-0.750111069630460,-0.770513242775789,-0.790155012375690,-0.809016994374947,-0.827080574274562,-0.844327925502015,-0.860742027003944,-0.876306680043864,-0.891006524188368,-0.904827052466020,-0.917754625683981,-0.929776485888251,-0.940880768954226,-0.951056516295154,-0.960293685676943,-0.968583161128631,-0.975916761938747,-0.982287250728689,-0.987688340595138,-0.992114701314478,-0.995561964603080,-0.998026728428272,-0.999506560365732,-1,-0.999506560365732,-0.998026728428272,-0.995561964603080,-0.992114701314478,-0.987688340595138,-0.982287250728689,-0.975916761938748,-0.968583161128631,-0.960293685676943,-0.951056516295154,-0.940880768954226,-0.929776485888252,-0.917754625683981,-0.904827052466020,-0.891006524188368,-0.876306680043864,-0.860742027003944,-0.844327925502015,-0.827080574274562,-0.809016994374948,-0.790155012375691,-0.770513242775789,-0.750111069630460,-0.728968627421411,-0.707106781186548,-0.684547105928689,-0.661311865323652,-0.637423989748690,-0.612907053652977,-0.587785252292473,-0.562083377852131,-0.535826794978997,-0.509041415750372,-0.481753674101715,-0.453990499739547,-0.425779291565072,-0.397147890634781,-0.368124552684679,-0.338737920245291,-0.309016994374948,-0.278991106039229,-0.248689887164854,-0.218143241396543,-0.187381314585725,-0.156434465040231,-0.125333233564305,-0.0941083133185140,-0.0627905195293132,-0.0314107590781283,-1.83697019872103e-16,0.0314107590781288,0.0627905195293128,0.0941083133185145,0.125333233564304,0.156434465040231,0.187381314585724,0.218143241396542,0.248689887164855,0.278991106039229,0.309016994374947,0.338737920245291,0.368124552684677,0.397147890634782,0.425779291565073,0.453990499739547,0.481753674101715,0.509041415750371,0.535826794978996,0.562083377852130,0.587785252292473,0.612907053652976,0.637423989748690,0.661311865323651,0.684547105928688,0.707106781186548,0.728968627421411,0.750111069630460,0.770513242775789,0.790155012375690,0.809016994374948,0.827080574274562,0.844327925502015,0.860742027003944,0.876306680043864,0.891006524188368,0.904827052466020,0.917754625683981,0.929776485888252,0.940880768954226,0.951056516295154,0.960293685676943,0.968583161128631,0.975916761938747,0.982287250728689,0.987688340595138,0.992114701314478,0.995561964603080,0.998026728428272,0.999506560365732,1

};
 double Ib[]={
  
  -0.50,-0.47,-0.44,-0.41,-0.38,-0.35,-0.32,-0.29,-0.26,-0.23,-0.207911690817759,-0.177084740319583,-0.146083028562411,-0.114937150492866,-0.0836778433323153,-0.0523359562429436,-0.0209424198833567,0.0104717841162461,0.0418756537291998,0.0732381971276319,0.104528463267654,0.135715572434305,0.166768746716103,0.197657340379126,0.228350870110656,0.258819045102521,0.289031796944472,0.318959309298070,0.348572047321815,0.377840786818467,0.406736643075800,0.435231099372328,0.463296035119862,0.490903753615141,0.518027009373131,0.544639035015027,0.570713567684432,0.596224874965616,0.621147780278310,0.645457687723951,0.669130606358858,0.692143173870407,0.714472679632804,0.736097087119735,0.756995055651757,0.777145961456971,0.796529918024196,0.815127795728554,0.832921240710100,0.849892692986864,0.866025403784439,0.881303452064992,0.895711760239413,0.909236109047069,0.921863151588501,0.933580426497202,0.944376370237481,0.954240328516277,0.963162566797658,0.971134279909636,0.978147600733806,0.984195607969242,0.989272332962988,0.993372765600396,0.996492859249504,0.998629534754574,0.999780683474846,0.999945169365512,0.999122830098858,0.997314477224458,0.994521895368273,0.990747840471444,0.985996037070505,0.980271174621722,0.973578902873160,0.965925826289068,0.957319497532067,0.947768410009586,0.937281989491891,0.925870584809995,0.913545457642601,0.900318771402194,0.886203579231215,0.871213811120189,0.855364260160506,0.838670567945424,0.821149209133704,0.802817475191114,0.783693457325840,0.763796028634642,0.743144825477394,0.721760228098362,0.699663340513365,0.676875969682660,0.653420603990105,0.629320391049837,0.604599114862375,0.579281172342679,0.553391549243344,0.526955795496677,0.500000000000000,0.472550764869054,0.444635179184927,0.416280792260401,0.387515586452103,0.358367949545300,0.328866646738583,0.299040792256087,0.268919820615265,0.238533457578581,0.207911690817760,0.177084740319583,0.146083028562411,0.114937150492867,0.0836778433323152,0.0523359562429437,0.0209424198833575,-0.0104717841162460,-0.0418756537291996,-0.0732381971276320,-0.104528463267654,-0.135715572434304,-0.166768746716102,-0.197657340379126,-0.228350870110656,-0.258819045102521,-0.289031796944472,-0.318959309298070,-0.348572047321816,-0.377840786818467,-0.406736643075801,-0.435231099372327,-0.463296035119862,-0.490903753615140,-0.518027009373130,-0.544639035015027,-0.570713567684432,-0.596224874965616,-0.621147780278310,-0.645457687723951,-0.669130606358858,-0.692143173870407,-0.714472679632804,-0.736097087119734,-0.756995055651757,-0.777145961456971,-0.796529918024196,-0.815127795728555,-0.832921240710100,-0.849892692986864,-0.866025403784439,-0.881303452064993,-0.895711760239413,-0.909236109047069,-0.921863151588501,-0.933580426497202,-0.944376370237481,-0.954240328516277,-0.963162566797658,-0.971134279909636,-0.978147600733806,-0.984195607969242,-0.989272332962988,-0.993372765600397,-0.996492859249504,-0.998629534754574,-0.999780683474846,-0.999945169365512,-0.999122830098858,-0.997314477224458,-0.994521895368273,-0.990747840471444,-0.985996037070505,-0.980271174621722,-0.973578902873160,-0.965925826289068,-0.957319497532067,-0.947768410009586,-0.937281989491891,-0.925870584809995,-0.913545457642601,-0.900318771402193,-0.886203579231215,-0.871213811120189,-0.855364260160507,-0.838670567945424,-0.821149209133704,-0.802817475191114,-0.783693457325840,-0.763796028634642,-0.743144825477394,-0.721760228098362,-0.699663340513365,-0.676875969682661,-0.653420603990106,-0.629320391049838,-0.604599114862375,-0.579281172342680,-0.553391549243343,-0.526955795496677,-0.500000000000000
  };
  double Ic[]={
    -0.50,-0.52,-0.55,-0.57,-0.60,-0.62,-0.65,-0.67,-0.69,-0.72,-0.743144825477395,-0.763796028634642,-0.783693457325840,-0.802817475191115,-0.821149209133704,-0.838670567945424,-0.855364260160507,-0.871213811120190,-0.886203579231215,-0.900318771402194,-0.913545457642601,-0.925870584809995,-0.937281989491892,-0.947768410009586,-0.957319497532068,-0.965925826289068,-0.973578902873160,-0.980271174621722,-0.985996037070505,-0.990747840471444,-0.994521895368273,-0.997314477224458,-0.999122830098858,-0.999945169365512,-0.999780683474846,-0.998629534754574,-0.996492859249504,-0.993372765600396,-0.989272332962988,-0.984195607969242,-0.978147600733806,-0.971134279909636,-0.963162566797658,-0.954240328516277,-0.944376370237481,-0.933580426497202,-0.921863151588500,-0.909236109047068,-0.895711760239413,-0.881303452064992,-0.866025403784439,-0.849892692986864,-0.832921240710099,-0.815127795728554,-0.796529918024196,-0.777145961456971,-0.756995055651756,-0.736097087119734,-0.714472679632803,-0.692143173870406,-0.669130606358858,-0.645457687723950,-0.621147780278310,-0.596224874965616,-0.570713567684431,-0.544639035015026,-0.518027009373130,-0.490903753615140,-0.463296035119861,-0.435231099372327,-0.406736643075800,-0.377840786818467,-0.348572047321815,-0.318959309298070,-0.289031796944471,-0.258819045102520,-0.228350870110656,-0.197657340379126,-0.166768746716102,-0.135715572434304,-0.104528463267653,-0.0732381971276315,-0.0418756537291992,-0.0104717841162455,0.0209424198833579,0.0523359562429442,0.0836778433323161,0.114937150492867,0.146083028562412,0.177084740319584,0.207911690817760,0.238533457578581,0.268919820615266,0.299040792256087,0.328866646738584,0.358367949545301,0.387515586452104,0.416280792260402,0.444635179184928,0.472550764869054,0.500000000000001,0.526955795496677,0.553391549243344,0.579281172342679,0.604599114862375,0.629320391049838,0.653420603990106,0.676875969682661,0.699663340513366,0.721760228098363,0.743144825477394,0.763796028634643,0.783693457325840,0.802817475191114,0.821149209133704,0.838670567945424,0.855364260160507,0.871213811120190,0.886203579231215,0.900318771402194,0.913545457642601,0.925870584809995,0.937281989491892,0.947768410009586,0.957319497532068,0.965925826289068,0.973578902873160,0.980271174621722,0.985996037070505,0.990747840471444,0.994521895368274,0.997314477224458,0.999122830098858,0.999945169365512,0.999780683474846,0.998629534754574,0.996492859249504,0.993372765600396,0.989272332962988,0.984195607969242,0.978147600733806,0.971134279909636,0.963162566797658,0.954240328516277,0.944376370237481,0.933580426497202,0.921863151588501,0.909236109047068,0.895711760239413,0.881303452064992,0.866025403784439,0.849892692986863,0.832921240710100,0.815127795728554,0.796529918024196,0.777145961456971,0.756995055651756,0.736097087119734,0.714472679632803,0.692143173870407,0.669130606358858,0.645457687723951,0.621147780278310,0.596224874965615,0.570713567684431,0.544639035015027,0.518027009373130,0.490903753615141,0.463296035119862,0.435231099372328,0.406736643075800,0.377840786818467,0.348572047321814,0.318959309298070,0.289031796944472,0.258819045102520,0.228350870110656,0.197657340379125,0.166768746716102,0.135715572434304,0.104528463267652,0.0732381971276307,0.0418756537291998,0.0104717841162452,-0.0209424198833574,-0.0523359562429441,-0.0836778433323164,-0.114937150492867,-0.146083028562412,-0.177084740319584,-0.207911690817760,-0.238533457578581,-0.268919820615266,-0.299040792256087,-0.328866646738584,-0.358367949545301,-0.387515586452103,-0.416280792260401,-0.444635179184928,-0.472550764869054,-0.500000000000000
 };
 
 /*double Ia[]={0.00,0.12,0.134,0.456,0.856};
  double Ib[]={0.00,0.12,0.134,0.456,0.856};
   double Ic[]={0.00,0.12,0.134,0.456,0.856};
 */
 double Ialpha[200]={};
 double Ibeta[200]={};
  double Theta[200]={};
  double u_q[200]={};
  double Uq_plus[200]={};
  double Ud_plus[200]={};
  double a=167.9877775;//filter gain
  double b=165.2122225;//filter gain
  double ylf[]={0.00,0.00};
  double c=200.00;
  double fo=0.00;
  double fn=50;
  double Ts=1/10000;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
//SystemClock_Config();
  Serial.setRx(PA10);
  Serial.setTx(PA9);
  Serial.begin(2400);
  //Serial.print("start");
}

void loop() {
  
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
for(int n=2;n<200;n++)
{ 
  Serial.print("n= ");

  Serial.print(n);
  Serial.println("Ia =");
  Serial.print(Ia[n]);
  Serial.println("Ib =");
  Serial.print(Ib[n]);
  Serial.println("Ic =");
  Serial.print(Ic[n]);

Ialpha[n] =(2.0/3.0)*(Ia[n]-0.5*(Ib[n]+Ic[n]));
Ibeta[n] =(2.0/3.0)*0.866*(Ib[n]-Ic[n]);

Serial.print("Ialpha =");
Serial.println(Ialpha[n]);
Serial.print("Ibeta =");
Serial.println(Ibeta[n]);

Ud_plus[n]=Ialpha[n]*cos(Theta[n])+Ibeta[n]*sin(Theta[n]);
Uq_plus[n]=-Ialpha[n]*sin(Theta[n])+Ibeta[n]*cos(Theta[n]);
u_q[0]=Uq_plus[n];  
ylf[0]=ylf[1]+a*u_q[0]-b*u_q[1];
ylf[0]=min(ylf[0],c);
u_q[1]=u_q[0];
ylf[1]=ylf[0];
fo=fn+ylf[0];
Serial.print("fo=");
Serial.println(fo);


Serial.print(Theta[2]);
Theta[n+1]=Theta[n]+(2*PI)*(fo*Ts);
if (Theta[n+1]>=((2*PI)-(2*PI)*(fo*Ts)))
{
Theta[n+1]=0;
}
Serial.print("ud =");
Serial.print(Ud_plus[n]);
Serial.print("uq =");
Serial.print(Uq_plus[n]);

}
ylf[0]=0.00;
ylf[1]=0.00;
Theta[0]=0.00;
Theta[1]=0.00;
Theta[2]=0.00;
Serial.println("ends");
/*for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
  Serial.print("ud =");
  Serial.print(Ud_plus[i]);
  }
  */
}
```

I have tried to locate the problem in the code, particularly in the line "Theta[n+1]=Theta[n]+(2PI)(fo*Ts);" where I suspect the issue lies. I expected the theta value to be calculated and updated properly, which is necessary for performing the d-q transformation accurately. However, due to the issue with the theta value calculation, I am not able to obtain the desired output after the d-q transformation.